# word boundaries to handle dot sign in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a variable which contains a string.  Now I want to use this variable in `awk` to put word boundaries. I am nearly able to do, but work boundaries are not working for `dot` sign. How to deal with this.  I have to stick with `awk` as I have some further actions to take based on columns.

## input variable:

```
echo $x
sam
```

## input data:

```
cat foo
t1.sam sample
sam bla
sample sam
```

## What I am getting:

```
awk -v test="$x" '$1~"\\<"test"\\>"' foo
t1.sam sample
sam bla
```

`grep -w` give the desired result but cannot use, also `grep  '\<sam\>' foo` works .but same `regex` is not working in `awk`.

Added example: if `a != 1` then print all the lines. if `a=1` then check if `$1` contains sam (with boundaries), if it does then print all the lines.

```
a=1;
x=sam;

if [ $a -eq 1 ];then

    awk -v test="$x" '$1 == test' foo #Print all the lines where $1 is sam. 

 else

    awk -v test="$x" '$1 ~ /./' foo #print all the lines where $1 is something. 


fi
```

## desired output:

when `a != 1`

```
sam bla
```

when `a == 1`

```
t1.sam sample
sam bla
sample sam
```

Comment: I am wondering, why not just `$1=="sam" or $1==test` since you have already used default `FS`

Comment: @Kent The reason for not using equality is: sometimes test=. , means print all the line where $1 conatins anything. , in equality, this will not work

Comment: That would only match one character surrounded by word boundaries though.

Comment: instead of `$1=="sam"` you are searching for overcomplicated ways

Comment: your `else` block is redundant - *where $1 is something* - `$1` is always be "something"

Comment: @Roman that's not true in the case of an empty line, or a different field separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create an optional filter, something like this:

```
awk -v test="$test" 'length(test) && $1 == test || !length(test)' file
```

Now if the shell variable `$test` is empty, all lines are printed. Otherwise, only lines whose first field are equal to `$test` are.

Using your file:

```
$ test=sam
$ awk -v test="$test" 'length(test) && $1 == test || !length(test)' file
sam bla
$ test=
$ awk -v test="$test" 'length(test) && $1 == test || !length(test)' file
cat foo
t1.sam sample
sam bla
sample sam
```

Comment: thanks for the help, had to tweak a bit and worked for me.

Comment: I was about to delete my answer because it makes more sense to handle the condition in the shell once and just `cat` the file in the `else` branch. To be honest I don't understand what the problem is with the example you've posted in the question.

Comment: I am using case statement and functions as their options, hence  i had to wrap the logic in one line so I could pipe it inside case statement.  I think I failed horribly to scale down the problem as example.

Answer (score 1):

DOT is not considered a word character hence boundary assertion doesn't work after `.`

It is better to use equality here:

```
awk -v test="$x" '$1 == test' file
sam bla
```

**EDIT:** As per your edited question you can use:

```
a=1
awk -v a=$a -v test="$x" '(a != 1 && $1 == test) || (a == 1 && $1 ~ test)' file
t1.sam sample
sam bla
sample sam

a=0
awk -v a=$a -v test="$x" '(a != 1 && $1 == test) || (a == 1 && $1 ~ test)' file
sam bla
```

Comment: The reason for not using equality is: sometimes `test=.` , means print all the line where `$1` conatins anything. , in equality, this will not work.

Comment: Can you clarify with an example in your question

Comment: A `.` **is** considered a word boundary, which is exactly why the line `t1.sam sample` matches.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that `DOT is not considered a word character`

Comment: I added an example, I want to do this in some shorter  way. in one `awk` statement.

Comment: Sorry example is still unclear. Your expected output is `sam bla` which is what I am also getting using equality check.

Comment: if `a != 1` then print all the lines. if `a=1` then check if `$1` contains `sam` (with boundaries) , if it does then print.