# Print header when match is found, else do not print header.

Tags: awk

I have following input file, and I need to put filter based on the column.

```
 cat test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client-code                       ID     BONUS   Availability           Offer       Credit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BLAB-LO.AJBdLODikNcpok            SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJBluDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDaLAgNEp                SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDaLDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDbLOAgNEp               SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDbLODikNcpok            SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJHbmLO                   SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOBollNcpok           SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOApkNamNk            SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
KONEAAO                           SK-19  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJHbmLO                   SK-11  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOBollNcpok           SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOApkNamNk            SK-10  0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
```

Here, I am putting filter on the second column, using equality, not regex, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339586/word-boundaries-to-handle-dot-sign-in-awk) 
.

```
awk -v userInput='SK-1' 'NR<4 || $2 == userInput' test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client-code                       ID     BONUS   Availibility           Offer       Credit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BLAB-LO.AJBluDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDaLDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJHbmLO                   SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOBollNcpok           SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
```

This works well if there is any match, however, if there is no match, I get empty header. I want to get rid of header lines. (first three lines.) .

This is not desired.

```
 awk -v userInput='SK-122' 'NR<4 || $2 == userInput' test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client-code                       ID     BONUS   Availibility           Offer       Credit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Desired:

When there is no match, I need to get:  Blank or no match found  message.

```
awk -v userInput='SK-122' 'NR<4 || $2 == userInput' test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v userInput='SK-1' '
    NR<4 { hdr = hdr $0 ORS; next }
    $2 == userInput { print hdr $0; hdr="" }
    END { if (hdr!="") print "No match found" }
' file
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client-code                       ID     BONUS   Availability           Offer       Credit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BLAB-LO.AJBluDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDaLDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJHbmLO                   SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOBollNcpok           SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to store the header and print it only when the first *userInput* is matched:

```
awk -v userInput='SK-1' 'NR<4{header=sprintf("%s%s\n", header,$0);next}$2 == userInput{if (!i){printf("%s",header)};i=1;print}' test
```

---

```
awk -v userInput='SK-1' 'NR<4{header=sprintf("%s%s\n", header,$0);next}
                 $2 == userInput{if (!i){printf("%s",header)};i=1;print}
                 END{if (!i){print "Not found"}}' test
```

Answer (score 2):

Buffer, print, clean:

```
$ awk -v i="SK-1" 'NR<4{b=b $0 "\n"} $2==i {b=b $0; print b; b=""}' file
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client-code                       ID     BONUS   Availability           Offer       Credit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BLAB-LO.AJBluDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJDaLDikNcpok             SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJHbmLO                   SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
BLAB-LO.AJAcLOBollNcpok           SK-1   0       AVAILABLE              OFFERED     NA
```